# Input masking and unmasking like xxx-xx-6789 (mask) and 123-45-6789 (unmask)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please anyone have done input masking on text box like xxx-xx-6789.

one text and one check box.

If checked on checkbox then apply masking like (xxx-xx-6789).
If Unchecked on checkbox then remove masking like (123-45-6789).

and both case actual value will be 123456789 (for save).

https://github.com/mishraas/jQuery-SSN-Field-Masking

Comment: What have you done so far? Please share the code.

Comment: Hope you are looking for this kind of thing?
http://jsfiddle.net/w2sccqwy/1/

Comment: yes @dgk but this is not working properly.

Comment: Could you please share your code so we can apply on that. Make fiddle and share it

Comment: https://github.com/mishraas/jQuery-SSN-Field-Masking     code is here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one check box as below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MaskUnmask" value="MaskUnmask" class="maskunmask"/>
```

and add change function in javascript as below it will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', { maskedChar: 'X', maskedCharsLength: 5 });

                $(".maskunmask").on("change", function () {

                    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        $('#ssn').unmask().mask('999-99-9999');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', { maskedChar: 'X', maskedCharsLength: 5 });
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of unmask input text box, use the mask format '999999999'.

```
var val = $('#ssn').mask('999999999').val();
```

Try the following, in following mask format applied and removed in checkbox event.

```
$('#ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', {maskedChar:'X', maskedCharsLength:5});


$("#check").change(function(){
var val = $('#ssn').mask('999999999').val();

 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        $('#ssn').unmask().mask('999-99-9999');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', { maskedChar: 'X', maskedCharsLength: 5 });
                    }
alert(val);
});
```